# Pagination Angular Firestore (FireBase)

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, geofirestore

I want to get next 4 documents in firestore startAt or startAfter not working correctly help me if anyone can do it

```
  getAllNearMeUser(city, offset, userDocumentLastKey?) {
      return this.angularFirestore.collection('members', x => 
      x.orderBy('createdAt','asc')
     .startAfter(userDocumentLastKey).limit(offset + 1))
     .snapshotChanges().map(docArray => {
      return docArray.map(doc => {
        return {
          key: doc.payload.doc.id,
          ...doc.payload.doc.data()
        };
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Try to save in your `userDocumentLastKey` last QueryDocumentSnapshot from recieved array, e.g. `userDocumentLastKey = docArray[docArray.lenght - 1].payload.doc;` and use it instead your `userDocumentLastKey`

Comment: Thanks Art i had done it basically i'm facing problem in document snapshot so i get first document snapshot then pass document snapshot to startAt